# My Minecraft Username Is 'Too Long'! Help!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I got a new login it set my username to my email, so now when I try to log onto servers it says that is unable to do so because my username is over 16 characters long. Does anybody know how to change it?

Comment: I'm not sure; Mojang should be your first priority though.

Comment: Try to contact Mojang support.

Comment: Get another account

Answer (score 1):

Contacting Mojang like @peper757 & @Damek suggested in the comments should be the first step you take, worst case scenario shorten your name that you're choosing. These are literally the only 2 ways to solve this.